# MVC5 repository and unitofwork pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to implement a search method: getCompte using account number and as a parametre but i could'nt get the response view!! i don't know where is the error

Form:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchCompte", "Compte", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("NumCompte", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
               <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.TextBox("NumCompte","", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "N° Compte" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("NumCompte", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                @Html.Label("CléRIB", new { @class = "col-md-1 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.TextBox("CléRIB", "",new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Clé" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("CléRIB", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class=" col-md-2">
                    <input type="submit" name="Search1" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

controller:

[HttpGet]

```
    public ActionResult SearchCompte()
    {
       //var Compte = new Compte();
        //var cp = service.GetComptes();
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SearchCompte(string NumCompte,string CléRIB)
    {
            try
            {
                long num = Convert.ToInt64(NumCompte);
                var cp = service.GetCompte(num);
                return View(cp);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "         The account doesn't exist";
                return View();
            } 

    }
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of at the top of my head is that your controller isn't named `Compte` or you have an `Authorize` attribute on there and you're not logged in.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint debugger in the post method to make sure it is getting there?

Comment: I removed the unit of work tag etc cause it's largely unrelated

Comment: yes i did !!! but i can't retrieve the view i am asked for :/

Comment: ok why, is it throwing an exception? if so, what is it?

Comment: your exception is indicating that num is null, try following what is happening inside service.GetCompte(num);

Comment: thanks for u guys.AmmarCSE thanks a lot ,the error was there and i fixed it.